# Decode base64 long string python3

Tags: python, base64

I trying to decode base64 long string, but result not legible text:

```
import base64
base64_string = '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'

sample_string_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
print(sample_string_bytes)
```

Result:

b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01u\xbf\x1f_>\x00\x00\x00\x05u0\x82\x05q0\x82\x04Y\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x12\x04\xad\x95\xa3g\xae\xf4\x97\\xd1Wt\xd0P\x7f/~V0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x0b\x05\x000J1\x0b0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02US1\x160\x14\x06\x03U\x04\n\x13\rLet's Encrypt1#0!\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x1aLet's Encrypt Authority X30\x1e\x17\r201113000145Z\x17\r210211000145Z0\x151\x130\x11\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\ngewamed.de0\x82\x01"0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x01\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x0f\x000\x82\x01\n\x02\x82\x01\x01\x00\xd1u\xbe\xb6\x9fV\xd5\xe7\x02\xc9]\x13hs\x96kf* ?\xe5(\xb6\x9e\xc0\xe7\x95\x08\xa4\xadJ\x19\x96\xc5\x10\xc7\x1dyQm;\xc3\x02\xd2\x95r\x98:\x95]\x929\xa9s\xdd\x89\x9e\xd4$\x1b\x1b\x18jM\xb9:\xb2\xc6\xb2\xa0\x07q\xd4N:\x82,\n\x19\xb8\xbc\xc6t\xe6]L\x06[\xd2\xe1\x96\xefE\xdb\xd5\xb9\xfd\x18\xac\xe9\x18$\xfa\x12\xb4\xfa_|\x9ciq}\xed\xcbc\xc1\xb0\xc6W\xd7V9\xdd\x13\x1f\xb4\xf1\x06B\xb1^,\xd3\xb5w\xa6Z\xe6\xa7\x06n3V(c\xd91U\xaba\xa1\xfb_\xd7\x90\x8c\xca\x8f[\x8ccA*L\x14\xa8\xf3wj\xcfc\x95\xc8\xb87\x02\xc2\xd6\x88\xaa\x02B\xcb\xbbX<\x94H\x08L\x12\x88wg\xd8\xc5~1(=\x02`\xda\xfdK\xa8\x87\x1ev\xbf\x18\x82\xc4*\xac\xf6\xe6\xa1Y\x8a\x11\xd2\x9b\x94\x8eV\x11t\x98_%r=\x04\xd1o\x94Z\xd2\x9c\x1b\xd8\xecg\xf0\xcc\x81\xb6\xce\xa6K\\\xa3>e\xcb\x02\x03\x01\x00\x01\xa3\x82\x02\x840\x82\x02\x800\x0e\x06\x03U\x1d\x0f\x01\x01\xff\x04\x04\x03\x02\x05\xa00\x1d\x06\x03U\x1d%\x04\x160\x14\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x03\x01\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x03\x020\x0c\x06\x03U\x1d\x13\x01\x01\xff\x04\x020\x000\x1d\x06\x03U\x1d\x0e\x04\x16\x04\x14\xed\xb1\xe6p\xbf3\xc1j\x1b7\xf6\x88\x0b\xca\x94E\x10NF\x850\x1f\x06\x03U\x1d#\x04\x180\x16\x80\x14\xa8Jjc\x04}\xdd\xba\xe6\xd19\xb7\xa6Ee\xef\xf3\xa8\xec\xa10o\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x01\x01\x04c0a0.\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x070\x01\x86"http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org0/\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x070\x02\x86#http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/09\x06\x03U\x1d\x11\x04200\x82\ngewamed.de\x82\x12webmail.gewamed.de\x82\x0ewww.gewamed.de0L\x06\x03U\x1d \x04E0C0\x08\x06\x06g\x81\x0c\x01\x02\x0107\x06\x0b+\x06\x01\x04\x01\x82\xdf\x13\x01\x01\x010(0&\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x02\x01\x16\x1ahttp://cps.letsencrypt.org0\x82\x01\x05\x06\n+\x06\x01\x04\x01\xd6y\x02\x04\x02\x04\x81\xf6\x04\x81\xf3\x00\xf1\x00w\x00\\\xdcC\x92\xfe\xe6\xabED\xb1^\x9a\xd4V\xe6\x107\xfb\xd5\xfaG\xdc\xa1s\x94\xb2^\xe6\xf6\xc7\x0e\xca\x00\x00\x01u\xbf\x1f^\xa1\x00\x00\x04\x03\x00H0F\x02!\x00\xdf\xf0E$\xd4\xc2^\xe9\'\x02\xdf\xa7\x00\x91iS\x06\x82\xf1\x9a\x18w\xc00&n\x07\xbe\xa4D\xe1)\x02!\x00\x90\xfc9\xd6\x1fE\xcb\xf5Q\x9e\x15S\xc7N\x89\x1c\x92\x1c\x89\xab\rb\xff\x9d\xf4\x88|\x87\xbcYs\x0b\x00v\x00\xf6\\\x94/\xd1w0"\x14T\x18\x080\x94V\x8e\xe3M\x13\x193\xbf\xdf\x0c/ \x0b\xccN\xf1d\xe3\x00\x00\x01u\xbf\x1f^\x85\x00\x00\x04\x03\x00G0E\x02 \n\x15i\x83\x96\xe1\xc9\xbd\x8d96\r\xce\xbf\xe11\xbd\xfa\t\xd7\xb4\xab,\xfd\xbd"_`\x97\xc2G\x7f\x02!\x00\xc3\xa1\xb4\xc7+\xc3\x95q\x125x\xf1U#\xd1\x93\xfcJD\xac\xe3\x88I\x1d`vU\xf8:\x08\x96\xeb0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x0b\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x01\x00gW\x99\xb1|3m\x0b\xa1N.|\x80\xf4\xe5\x0e\x1c\xd3\x8f\x99\x8c\xaf<\xa5\x10\xcd\xa7\xf7\x14u\x9b\x80P\xc6\x95\xa2c\x96\xab\x184[z\x07\xa3f\xb6\xf60\xa2\x7f\xd9\xb5\x83\xecY>TM\x12\x8e*\xb1\x8a8\xf0\xa7\xe5\xb9@\xe1MK\xa8\x03\x11\xac\tQ[\xab4\xcf"\xbf\xdc1\x93.\x1aG`]0 \xc2\x8e\x94l\xf69\xeb\x97i2\xd7\x13\xd1\xba\x10\x9f\x90m7\xb5\xe2\x08L\x97\xf8\xd5p\xf34i\x12X8\xbd\xc4\xab\xeb\x11K\xc8tV\xc5Rx\x7f\x07Q\xea\xac\xd3\xfb\x83]\x94\xfb>\xbb\x85\x90\xa0b\xf6\xdcF?\xc1\xb5\x1eh=\x94iX\xd7D\xc4\xa9k\x10\xaf\xc1\xd9\x95\xb1\x02\xea6\xd3l\xf0L\xaf\x8d\x8d\xe4\xde\x11\xb6\x82\x1d\x9aL\xe3\xdb\x95\x956\xceR\xfe\x1b\xe4\xe2g\xbb@\xc2F"\xd9!\xc6k)\x14\x19\x894\x91Z\x0b\x98<{\x82\xe8\xdetL\x84S\xf0\xbds\xcf:)\x16_\xee\x0cR\xaf\xf6\x14%\r\x01Ik\x00\x00'

Comment: The purpose of base64 encoding is to convert binary text into an easily printable format.  There is no reason it should be readable.  If it were, they wouldn't have used base64 in the first place.

Comment: in the fourth line of the output you can read *Let's Encrypt Authority*, which is a hint that it is encrypted.

Comment: Try this site to decode without python --> https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/

Answer (score 0):

You have to then decode to ascii if you want it to be readable.

Although the base64 you supplied doesn't seem to be valid ascii, so you messed up somewhere in regard to wherever you produced this Base64 if it is supposed to decode correctly to ascii.

It seems that whatever text you are using is encrypted. Base64 encryptions do not always hold ascii text, and in your case this is likely due to the encryption.

```py
import base64
base64_string = 'UHl0aG9uIGlzIGZ1bg=='

message_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
message = message_bytes.decode('ascii')

print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks Laif!. Your code generate this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decode64.py", line 5, in <module>
    message = message_bytes.decode('ascii')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Nietsmaf please read my edit

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to decode something to ASCII which is not ASCII.

Comment: @jps based on the question I assumed that was the goal, since he wants to print it out to quote: "legible text"

Comment: the question is based on the common misconception that you always get human-readable text after decoding a base64 string. And if you take a closer look at the output, you'll notice that there are a few pieces of ASCII in there, eg. "Let's Encrypt Authority" in the fourth line. So basically OPs code works fine and print ASCII where it finds ASCII. The rest is binary.

Comment: @jps interesting, I'll edit my answer to include this info